# XSL Template passing path as string

Tags: xml, xslt, transform

I am trying to pass an xml path as string to the template.

```
<xsl:call-template name="checkPath">
    <xsl:with-param name="path" select="'parent/child1'" />
</xsl:call-template>
```

Inside the template, i am appending a child to the passed string to check for the existence of a child element with the path and a given name.

```
<xsl:template name="checkPath">
    <xsl:param name="path"/>
    <xsl:variable name="childElement" select="child-name"/>
    <xsl:if test="$path/child2[name=$childElement]">
         //Do some processing.  
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

The above XSL gives me the following error.

```
Invalid conversion from 'java.lang.String' to 'node-set'.
```

I am trying to parse the below XML.

```
<parent>
    <child1>
        <child2>
            <name>name1</name>
        </child2>
    </child1>
</parent>

.....
<child-name>name1</child-name>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't pass the path as a string, just remove the quotes and pass the actual node set that the path selects.

```
<xsl:call-template name="checkPath">
    <xsl:with-param name="path" select="parent/child1" />
</xsl:call-template>
```